# android listview scrolling error

Tags: android, database, listview

I am having problem with my listview, the data is perfectly working but when im scrolling it down the title keeps repeating but the content when i click it is working. [image]

this is the image in the emulator.

[image]

this is the data in my database

here is the code I use in the listview

```
dataset_cursor = helper.getBooksByTitle2();   
startManagingCursor(dataset_cursor);        
adapter = new ContentAdapter(dataset_cursor);
list.setAdapter(adapter);`

class ContentAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
    ContentAdapter(Cursor c)
    {
        super(LEGALe.this, c);
    }
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c)
    {
        ContentHolder holder = (ContentHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }
    public View newView (Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, parent, false);
        ContentHolder holder = new ContentHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return(row);
    }
}

public Cursor getBooksByTitle2()
{
    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,table_of_content FROM tblContent WHERE title_id='"+ LEGALe.passedVar.toString() +"' ORDER BY table_of_content" , null));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with view item's recycling. I think you are not managing **getView** correctly.

However, my suggestion is to set your title as a view in list's header using `addHeaderView`.
Or, perhaps take it totally out from *ListView* (so it is constantly visible) and set separately as `TextView` above of your *ListView*.

Comment: can u provide some codes coz I did not get it :D thanks for the response

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter

Comment: thanks for the tip :D it really does not recycle properly, finally got it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost data to show inside listview as i see in your question ,android create only that much instances of list items that are visible on the activity, after your scroll the list it assigns that same instances to other items an so on.. thats why when your scrolling title keeps repeating

for example if the list shows 10 items like item1,item2-------item10 means 10 instances are created after you scroll to see 11th item android assigns 1 instanse for 12 2 instance and so on

Comment: is there a solution so the listview will not repeat the first data shown?

Comment: can you post your getview method

Answer (score 0):

your adapter doesnt seem implemented properly, do it as follows:

```
dataset_cursor = helper.getBooksByTitle2();
startManagingCursor(dataset_cursor);
adapter = new ContentAdapter(dataset_cursor); list.setAdapter(adapter);

class ContentAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{ 
       ContentAdapter(Cursor c) 
       { 
           super(LEGALe.this, c); 
       } 
       public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) 
       { 
           //Get Item from Cursor
           //Set values to views
       } 
       public View newView (Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) 
       { 
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, parent, false); 
            return(row); 
        } 
   }

   public Cursor getBooksByTitle2() 
   { 
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,table_of_content FROM tblContent WHERE                title_id='"+ LEGALe.passedVar.toString() +"' ORDER BY table_of_content" , null)); 
   }
```